# Python's End Of Life

Tags: python

What exactly will
happen to Python 2.7 after 1/2020?

I understand that Python 2.7 will no longer be supported but what will actually happen? Does it mean that decision makers will delete the whole codebase for Python 2.7 and will leave Python 3.x only?

How does it happen that a version of programming language will cease to exist?

Comment: **Nothing.** The released versions of 2.7 will still be available (as many other unsupported versions are right now [on the Python site](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and elsewhere). It just won't get any updates any more.

Comment: It’ll explode. Not.

Comment: Perhaps most importantly, many major library maintainers have pledged to stop supporting Python 2 on the same date: https://python3statement.org/

Comment: So all it means is that maintainers will no longer be releasing any improvements or patches for 2.7 and will focus on 3.x only ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: It’ll exploden’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In March 2018, Python inventor Guido van Rossum remarked:

> Let's not play games with semantics. The way I see the situation for
>   2.7 is that EOL is January 1st, 2020, and there will be no updates, not even source-only security patches, after that date. Support (from
>   the core devs, the PSF, and python.org) stops completely on that date.
>   If you want support for 2.7 beyond that day you will have to pay a
>   commercial vendor. Of course it's open source so people are also
>   welcome to fork it. But the core devs have toiled long enough, and the
>   2020 EOL date (an extension from the originally annouced 2015 EOL!)
>   was announced with sufficient lead time and fanfare that I don't feel
>   bad about stopping to support it at all.

Source: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2018-March/152348.html

Answer (score 1):

Read the second paragraph (emphasis mine):

> The End Of Life date (EOL, sunset date) for Python 2.7 has been moved
>   five years into the future, to 2020. This decision was made to clarify
>   the status of Python 2.7 and relieve worries for those users who
>   cannot yet migrate to Python 3. See also [PEP
>   466](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0466).
>
> **This declaration does not guarantee that bugfix releases will be made
>   on a regular basis, but it should enable volunteers who want to
>   contribute bugfixes for Python 2.7 and it should satisfy vendors who
>   still have to support Python 2 for years to come.**

Source: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/

In other words, maintainers will no longer be releasing any improvements or patches for 2.7 and will focus on 3.x only.